# cant open camera in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, ros

```
import cv2

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture('video/ros.mp4')

while(True):
    retVal, frame = video_capture.read()
    
    #frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #frame = cv2.resize(frame, (0,0), fx=0.5,fy=0.5)
    #cv2.line(frame,(0,0),(511,511),(255,0,0),5)
    cv2.imshow("Frame",frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

its my code in ubuntu 20.04 but cant open the camera the result is [image: result]

Comment: Do you have a camera on this machine?  Is it busy doing something else?

Comment: Whats the camera model ? Did you try other options like: VideoCapture(1), VideoCapture(2), VideoCapture(-1)...

Comment: I tried a lot...

Comment: the cheese camera was blank screen too.. i was configured in preference but still same.

Comment: @ImanFirmansyah then it could be problem with the camera itself. BTW is it real PC or virtualbox ?

Comment: For future questions please avoid posting screenshots of error messages but instead copy the message and add it as plain text.  This helps making the question easier to read and to find (e.g. when searching for the error message via google).

Comment: You should have just improved your most recent question instead of deleting it (I could have left this comment there), but I wrote a quick sample for one way to show the parts of an integer here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/P6YY3g

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue while running opencv code in ubuntu 20.04 on vmware.

Tried Below:

Open Player->Manage->Virtual Machine Settings -> Usb Controller -> Change the Usb Controller under Connections to USB 3.1 or USB 1.1 . Both resolved my issue.   Initially, it was by default set to USB 2.0. Hope it helps.